# Spring annotations analog for property-placeholder

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have spring XML configuration. I need to rewrite it by using Spring annotations.

The question is straight: is there a direct alternative for Spring XML statement `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/*.properties"/>` among spring annotations, which will work with locations masked like in example (`classpath*:META-INF/*.properties`)? Or some alternative, which will scan my classpath and find all property files there.

I tried `@PropertySource`, but it looks like don't understand masking. Putting direct paths to property files is not an option in my case, because their count may vary independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative I was seeking for was declaring this bean in configuration:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propPlaceholder() throws Exception {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:META-INF/*.properties"));
    return propertyConfigurer;
}
```

It's not annotation but still a replacement for that XML statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConfigurableApplicationContext class and also can load properties files from different locations as well as follows:

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:application,application2",
                        "spring.config.location:classpath:/external/application/properties/,classpath:/external/application2/properties")
                .build().run(args);


    ConfigurableEnvironment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
```

where the value under "spring.config.name" specifies the name of properties files (here application.properties and application2.properties) and the values under "spring.config.location" specifies the path of the above mentioned application files respectively